# Angular 5 Reactive form : how to dynamically add validators on a formcontrol, and show errors when a user submits the form

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm trying to dynamically set and remove **required validator** which seems to work (validates onBlur and onSubmit) if user has  clicked on the field before submitting. However, an untouched form submission does not validate the controls.

> **Usecase**:
>   User should be able to traverse form without errors showing up for required field. If user enters some data and the field has other validation, it should validate that and show errors on blur.
>   If a user submits a form without filling out required fields, errors should show up. When the user focuses back on the field, error should disappear. However, if the user now exits the field without typing in anything (empty), required error should show up.

I have a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/X91VjHmMp1W1LuUdcKy1?p=preview)  to demo what I have so far.

```
export class App implements OnInit {
name: string;
myform: FormGroup;
email: FormControl;

constructor() {
  this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
}

myform: FormGroup;
email: FormControl;

ngOnInit() {
  this.createFormControls();
  this.createForm();
}

  onSubmit() {
 console.log('sumbitted');
  this.email.setValidators([
    Validators.required,
    specialCharValidator]);
this.email.updateValueAndValidity()
}

createFormControls() {
this.email = new FormControl('', {
  updateOn: 'blur', validators: [
    Validators.required,
    specialCharValidator
  ]
  });
}

  createForm() {
this.myform = new FormGroup({
  email: this.email,
});
}

errorAdd(check) {
if (check.target.checked) {
  this.email.setValidators([
    Validators.required,
    specialCharValidator]);
  console.log('on');
} else {
  console.log('off');
  this.email.setValidators([specialCharValidator]);
  this.email.updateValueAndValidity()
  }
}

}
```

Comment: You are going slightly off the direction. The validation rules should always be there, it's just the error should be hidden if fields are untouched and form is not submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the form was validating correctly, i was just not using the info to display the error properly.
Updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/X91VjHmMp1W1LuUdcKy1?p=preview

```
submitted: boolean;
onSubmit() {
this.submitted = true;
}
```

and in template

```
*ngIf="alphanumeric.errors && ( submitted || alphanumeric.dirty || alphanumeric.touched)">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should add/remove validators dynamically, a better approach would be to turn on/off the error messages depending on the state of the fields (dirty/pristine/touched). This way you can control when the errors are shown in the UI by creating your custom rules. e.g

```
this.form.get(field).valid && this.form.get(field).touched
```